# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIkeyBoardDidShowNotification

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I am making a done button on numberpad keyboard iphone , as shown in the [following tutorial](http://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/tutorial-creating-a-done-button-on-the-iphone-number-pad-keyboard/#comment-78).

When I use `UIKeyBoardWillShowNotification` `[tempWindow.subviews count]` is coming out to be “0″ as keyboard is not yet added , then if i use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` it works fine except that done button image is added with a delay …
If anyone knows the reason for this , please submit and if possible - provide solution.